# Click to call application in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am wondering about an iPhone application called [Call Recorder - IntCall](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/call-recorder-intcall/id521680097?mt=8).

Can anybody explain how a number can be dialed via an application without using the device numberpad and cellular network? What API provides this service? I have seen many third-party click to call services, but is there an API available for mobile apps on iOS or Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make calls on the cellular network, only the default dialer app can do this.

The app in your link is a VoIP app and uses its own VoIP client to record the conversation.

Comment: any idea how i can create a VOIP application? Any sample code?

Comment: No, and there are many opensource libraries for VOIP clients. It is also very depended on the VOIP server that you plan to use.

Comment: Hm,
Thanks for the info. Searching for libraries those i can easily implement. Must let me know if you have any idea. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

We are the developers of this app. As rckoenes said, it's a VoIP app and uses a VoIP library and our VoIP server to implement the recording.

There are a few VoIP libraries, some free, but we have purchased a library (expensive).

In general VoIP is not that easy to implement. You need to understand the protocol and you need to have a server that supports what your apps need to do.